# Tinymce not sending the content after submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, tinymce

I'm not a professional programmer, I've had little experience working with Javascript and so this Tinymce is confusing me. Basically my client wants to update the content himself without touching the code, so I have to set up this Tinymce so he can edit the content directly on browser. I've followed the instruction to install Tinymce but when I click either save or submit, the editing frame refreshes itself and shows the same content without any change. Below is my code in the HTML page I want to edit. **Other than this HTML page, I don't have any other php or html page. Please tell me what I need to do.**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>

<script>
  tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea#elm1",
        theme: "modern",
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        plugins: [
             "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
             "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
             "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor"
       ],
       content_css: "css/content.css",
       toolbar: "save | insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | print preview media fullpage | forecolor backcolor emoticons", 
       style_formats: [
            {title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b'},
            {title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
            {title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
            {title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1'},
            {title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2'},
            {title: 'Table styles'},
            {title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1'}
        ],

         setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('change', function () {
            tinymce.triggerSave();
        });
    }
    }); 

</script>
```

And this is my code for the form in the same HTML page:

```
 <form method="post" action="news.html">
     <textarea id="elm1">The content I wanna edit</textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submitform" value="Sendform"></form>
```

Thanks very much guys!!

**UPDATE 1:** From the first answer and from other answers I collected from the internet, I've managed to get my code like this, but it still doesn't work, the Submit button seems do to nothing when I click on it now.

In the HTML page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>

<script>
  tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea#elm1",
        theme: "modern",
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        plugins: [
             "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
             "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
             "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor"
       ],
       content_css: "css/content.css",
       toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | print preview media fullpage | forecolor backcolor emoticons", 
       style_formats: [
            {title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b'},
            {title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
            {title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
            {title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1'},
            {title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2'},
            {title: 'Table styles'},
            {title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1'}
        ],

         setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('change', function () {
            tinymce.triggerSave();
        });
    }
    }); 

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

  var url = "news.php";

  $("#SubmitBtn").click(function(){
    //"content" will PHP variable 
    $.post(url, { "page_content" : tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent() }, function(respond){

       if ( respond == ){
          alert('Content saved to file');
          return;
       } else {
          //Error message assumed
          alert(respond);
        }
    });
  });

});

</script>
```

The form:

```
<form method="post" action="news.php">
 <textarea id="elm1" name="page_content">The content I wanna edit</textarea>
        <input type="button" id="SubmitBtn" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
```

In the PHP page:

```
<?php

if ( isset($_POST['page_content']) ){

   //This is what you want - HTML content from tinyMCE
   //just treat this a string

   if ( save_html_to_file($_POST['page_content'], 'news.html') ){
     //Print 1 and exit script
     die(1);
   } else {
      die('Couldnt write to stream');
   }
}

/**
 * 
 * @param string $content HTML content from TinyMCE editor
 * @param string $path File you want to write into
 * @return boolean TRUE on success
 */
function save_html_to_file($content, $path){
   return (bool) file_put_contents($path, $content);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`<form method="post" action="news.html">` - in the `action` property, you need to change it to a PHP file (or whatever language you'd like), where you can write a script to process the data sent. What happens is that the data from TinyMCE will be sent in a variable to the server, and you need to save it to a database of some sort. I'm assuming `news.html` is a static page - it will have to run off of a database for the client to update it.

Do some research on saving and reading from a MySQL database with PHP, and saving data from a form.

You'd need to give your textarea a `name` -- `<textarea id="elm1" name="page-content">`

You would then access what was submitted in PHP like this:

```
$content = $_POST['page-content'];
```

and then you can save it to a database or whatever you wish.

Comment: Hey, thank you. I've updated my code regarding your suggestion, I added codes from other answers too. But it still doesn't work. Can you please take a look at my update? Thank you.

Comment: What does happen? Does it just go to a white screen, or it looks like it works and the page doesn't change, etc?

Comment: Well when click submit, the page doesn't change or go to a white page, the editing frame is still there. The content stay the same as edited but when I refresh the page, the content shows the original again. I wonder what's wrong